# Plotting the number of entries in the dataset depending on the date

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, data-science

I have this dataset (screen)
[image]

1. How to draw plot with histograms of label distribution (its only 0 or 1) based on years
2. How to draw linear plot, where X coord is the date (year) and Y coord is the number of entries made in a given year

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your dates are stored as datetime objects, then you can use the following :

```
import seaborn as sns
years=df['date'].dt.year
sns.distplot(years)
```

For the label, you can use :

```
label=1#0, you choose
df_lab=df.loc['label'==label]
years_label=df_lab['date'].dt.year
sns.distplot(years_label)
```

Comment: what if it has date type?

Comment: you can use :  `years=pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.year `

Comment: thanks. but on Y ax i see some values like 1.5, 2, 3 (not real count). how to fix it?

Comment: and if you can, please, tell, how to draw plot with histograms of label distribution (its only 0 or 1) based on years

Comment: you should be able to display the real count by using :
`df['year']=df['date'].dt.year `
`sns.distplot(df,x='years') `